# db.create_all() 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'

Tags: python, postgresql

I am following the CS50's Web Programming with Python and Javascript and in Lecture4 I have had the following error trying to create a postgresql database table:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "create.py", line 15, in main
    db.create_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 963, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 955, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 896, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, info, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 830, in apply_driver_hacks
    if info.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

The code that I have used is in two python file:
The first 1 called models.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Flight(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "flights"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    origin = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    destination = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class Passenger(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "passengers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    flight_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("flight.id"), nullable=False)
```

The second file is called create.py:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        main()
```

Can you help me?!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this is an issue with how you're attempting to connect to your `Postgres` database:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1")
```

you probably want this line to be the following instead:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1"
```

since the `os.getenv(...)` is currently trying to get an environment variable on your system named: `"postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1"` and you surely didn't set up an environment variable with this name.. Which is why you're getting a `NoneType` error for your `postgres` driver:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'.

If you want to use an environment variable to get your database connection string, do something like the following in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file:

```
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1'
```

then change your database connection code to the following:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```

Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

To clarify gbajson's answer, `os.getenv` gets a value from a specific environment variable. You *either* need to store the database URI in an env var (before you start Flask) and get it from there:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URI")
```

or, hard code it directly as a string without using getenv:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1"
```

Comment: I have same kind of issues, unable to connect my docker volume via Config, will you look into these issues?,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61106345/2034750

Answer (score 1):

Check line `os.getenv("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database1")`

It doesn't contain the name of the environment variable.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=getenv#os.getenv

Sample usage:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 20 2018, 15:06:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os  
>>> editor = os.getenv('EDITOR')
>>> print(editor)
vi
```

Answer (score 0):

I am creating web application blog based on Flask, which is connecting to database via SQLAlchemy module.

When running application on server, I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'`, which brought me here. 
What I had as environment attributes before (locally in development), now I have as `config.json` file for production. 
To access that, I use:
`with open('path/to/config.json') as config_file:` and then save that configuration as python dictionary in variable with `config = json.load(config_file)`.

I named my sql variable exactly like this: 
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = config.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')`
I named it exactly the same way in my config.json file to which it goes.

I was looking for a problem withing packages installed in my virtual environment but that didn't help. What was the problem is that I made a typo, calling my json key "SQALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI" inside my config.json, missing "L". This type of dumb typo got me exactly same error, making me spend too much time on that, so perhaps if someone is looking for a similar solution, double check your syntax/spelling first.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly: this can be caused by SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI not being set.