# How to connect docker volume 'database/app.db' to SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, docker-volume

I am using `Python 3.8.1` `Flask latest` and app running fine but unable to connect the docker volume from SQLAlchemy and if the database does not exist it should create the database, but I am unable to connect my shared docker volume into my `Python Flask` app.

Config.py file:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATA_PATH = "/database"

if os.path.exists(DATA_PATH) == False:
    os.mkdir(DATA_PATH)

class Config(object):

    # set a proper secret key here or is the .flaskenv file
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://database/app.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

**init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

from app import routes, models
```

Docker run :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it --name abc -v localdb:/database  --rm abc:v1
```

Error 1:

```
xc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid SQLite URL: 
sqlite://database//app/app/app.db
Valid SQLite URL forms are:
 sqlite:///:memory: (or, sqlite://)
 sqlite:///relative/path/to/file.db
 sqlite:////absolute/path/to/file.db
```

Error 2:

For    `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///database/app.db'`

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like a Docker volume issue, it looks like you are trying to access the database using a path as the URI instead of: `sqlite:////path/to/db.db`

See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#database-urls

Specifically for sqlite: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlite

Comment: I have tried like this: `sqlite:////database/app.db`, where the database is a directory of container which points to docker volume. but getting this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'`